# When does Stacking save?

Tags: stacking

When you exit Stacking, you receive a warning that unsaved progress will be lost. However, I've never seen any indication that the game has saved my progress.

**How do I know what will be saved and what will be lost when I exit the game?**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game might not be very good at indicating when it saves, but it actually does save after just about every bit of progress. After doing some testing, here is a list of events that cause the game to save:

- Completing a solution to a puzzle
- Stacking with a new unique doll
- Completing a Hijinks task
- Making progress towards completing a Hijinks task
- Moving between areas (eg. Moving from the room with the clocks to the ticket booth in the train station will save the game)

This covers just about everything in the game, but here are a few things that aren't saved:

- Your exact position in the game. When you resume the game after exiting, you revert back to a starting location that's unique to that area.
- The dolls you're currently stacked with. You always enter the game as Charlie Blackmore, so any dolls you stack with before quitting will not be saved.